# Accessing data in structure from a thrust vector

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

It looks like the `operator[]` of a `thrust::vector` return a `thrust::reference` that cannot be used to access data inside a structure.

Imagine I have

```
struct Point{
    int x,y
}
int main(){
    thrust::device_vector<Point> myvec;
    // ... I fill in the vector ...
    (myvec[0]).x = 4; // This line fails
    return 0;
}
```

`(myvec[0]).x = 4;` fails with `error: class "thrust::device_reference<Point>" has no member "x"`

I also tried:

```
Point &p = myvec[0];
p.x = 4;
```

but this fails with `error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue`

The only thing that works is

```
Point p = myvec[0];
p.x = 4;
```

but it doesn't do what I want…

How can I modify `(myvec[0]).x`?

Note that I am working on a more complicated stuff, and that this example might not be relevant.

---

Edit: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate.
The solution is weird but definitely the only way to go.

Comment: `Point p = myvec[0]; p.x = 4; myvec[0] = p;`

Comment: note that the method that you have edited into your question, using `thrust::raw_pointer_cast` does NOT work.  It appears to compile, but if you run it, it will generate a seg fault. The `raw_pointer_cast` operation  creates an ordinary device pointer (stored in `p`).  When you dereference that device pointer in host code:  `p->x = 4;` you will get a seg fault.  device pointers must not be dereferenced in host code.